# WebRequest и HTTPS с сертификатом sha256ECDSA

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

Реализую простейший пример запроса web-странички:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string html = string.Empty;
    string url = "https://ifconfig.co/ip";
    //string url = "https://ya.ru/"; // Что характерно - с этой ссылкой всё нормально
    try{
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string line = "";
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }     
        }
        response.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Запрос выполнен");
    } catch (Exception e){
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        if(e.InnerException != null) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

Получаю исключение:

Запрос был прерван: Не удалось создать защищенный канал SSL/TLS.
Судя по [журналу трассировки](https://pastebin.com/KYCBDn04) действительно, платформа .NET не может соединиться с сайтом ifconfig.co Скорее всего, потому что на web-сервер установлен сертификат с алгоритмом подписи sha256ECDSA
Из всех браузеров же сайт открывается нормально.
Возможно требуются какие-то настройки среды .NET?

Comment: Сайт [поддерживает TLS 1.2 и 1.3](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ifconfig.co&s=104.28.19.94&hideResults=on&latest). Возможно, у вас просто старая операционка, типа XP и совершенно необновлённые библиотеки криптографии? У меня приведённый код отработал без проблем на win10.

Comment: Попробуйте включить поддержку tls 1.2 (она выключена по умолчанию), через ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

Comment: Да, действительно, добавление строки 
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
в начале кода решило проблему.
Странно, но у меня даже на обновлённой Windows 10 без этой строчки не работало.
Хотелось бы понять смысл этой конструкции